# Getting a lot of crashes from android youtube player api

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using version 1.2.1 (tried with latest version 1.2.2) of `android's youtube player api`. It works fine on most of the devices. However now and then, I keep on getting crashes on crashlytics. I am getting the following crashes

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
   at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x(SourceFile:558)
   at bpd.w(SourceFile:576)
   at tef.onTransact(SourceFile:390)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:395)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.d$a$a.r(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.s.h(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.e(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1936)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1654)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1722)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1938)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1654)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1722)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
   at com.newshunt.news.activities.NewsBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(NewsBaseActivity.java:56)
   at com.newshunt.news.activities.NewsDetailsActivity.onSaveInstanceState(NewsDetailsActivity.java:613)
   at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1388)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1286)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4588)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3960)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4023)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:181)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6117)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Also getting crashes for the following exception.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
   at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.jar.a.eo.surfaceDestroyed(SourceFile:236)
   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:589)
   at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:237)
   at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:12854)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2757)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2757)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3844)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3819)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3751)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.h(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1111)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1125)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

The crash happens to appear in specific versions of youtube application like 5.2.27. Although there are a lot of issues filed for these crashes, there has been no reply from the youtube developers on how to mitigate this issue.

Some of the fellow developers have suggested the following workarounds

1) Use `loadVideo` instead of `cueVideo`. But I cannot use this workaround because `loadVideo` always autoplays the video which is not a requirement of my application. Also someone mentioned that with `loadVideo` also, this problem is happening although in some different version.

2) Put check in the code to check the youtube application version and then put the specific code. Now the problem with this approach is that I have to check each and every version of youtube app ever released and check which versions are causing the issue which is not a good workaround.

Now is there any fix which I can apply to avoid this issue or are the youtube developers planning to release some jar which internally takes care of all these issues?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: latest is 1.2.2.. Please have a look on this

Comment: @AkarshM  checked, it is crashing in this version as well.

Comment: Is your app having Next or Previous Feature like PlayList for youtube Video ?

Comment: Were you the latest one to update this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4395) on their public tracker? It seems like a similar inquiry

Comment: @adjuremods. yes, I did update there as well.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger have you managed to solve the issue with TransactionTooLargeException?

Comment: @thedarkpassenger :I am facing the same issue, have you find any workaround of this

Comment: @MukeshY: not yet

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the bug occurrence by putting youtube calls (like youtubePlayer.loadVideo(), cueVideo(), getCurrentTimeMillis() etc.) in a try catch block and catch the IllegalStateException exception then reinitialize youtube player.

To create a new instance of the YoutubePlayer just call the initialize() method in the catch block.

Example:

```
 if (youtubePlayer != null) {
        try {
            youtubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
    }
```

but the bug still occurred , I worked around it by catching these exceptions and restart activity. This uncaught exceptions and to catch them you need to use UncaughtExceptionHandler

example :

```
 private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    // setup handler for uncaught exception
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(_unCaughtExceptionHandler);
}

   private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler _unCaughtExceptionHandler =
                new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "uncaughtException: ", ex);
                        PendingIntent myActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                                192837, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager;
                        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                15000, myActivity );
                        System.exit(2);

                        // re-throw critical exception further to the os (important)
                        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

The android YouTube Player API is not stable, there are [known bugs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172585) in it. The team from YouTube said that they will release a new version of the library.

For now, the best solution I have found is to build [my own library](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player).