# OutOfMemoryError occurs using YouTube Android player api 1.2.2

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Play video using youtube player sdk about 30~40 times causes Youtube application crashes, then a DeadObjectException will raise from my app due to the death of remote process. steps to reproduce:

1. launch activity and initialize YouTubePlayer
2. load and play a video for a few seconds
3. release YouTubePlayer and exit activity
4. repeat step 1-3 about 30~40 times

OutOfMemoryError log([full logs](https://gist.github.com/sd148684/27968841cc52c7f52cffd0a0b0293d3c)):

```
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017): Process: com.google.android.youtube.player, PID: 3017
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1556)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:310)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:527)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:616)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at reo.a(SourceFile:134)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at sgh.a(SourceFile:722)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at gan.a(SourceFile:310)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at gan.b(SourceFile:338)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.ApiPlayerService$2.run(SourceFile:215)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-22 12:01:01.461 E/AndroidRuntime( 3017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and DeadObjectException

```
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976): java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at gix.surfaceCreated(SourceFile:189)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.ISurfaceHolderService$Stub$Proxy.a(SourceFile:110)
08-22 12:01:01.842 E/MonitoringInstrumentation( 2976):  at gix.surfaceCreated(SourceFile:186)
```

YouTube App version is 11.29.55 , Nexus 5 emulator with Marshmallow
, I've tested it with other versions of YouTube App like 10.25.57 and 10.40.58, the OOM still occurs.

At the very beginning when I encounter this issue I thought it was just caused by some incorrectly api method calls, but after so many hours research I figured out it should be a YouTube App's issue, hope someone can help me to resolve it, or at least avoid it.

The memory of process `com.google.android.youtube.player` is increasing while player initialization and video playing from Memory Monitor, and many `YoutubeService` instances created but not recycled from the dump file. Any idea?

I test it with a demo application based on the official YouTubeAndroidAPI sample and the OutOfMemory error occurs as well, I just replaced `cueVideo(String)` by `loadVideo(String)` in `PlayerViewDemoActivity` for auto-playing, and added `YouTubePlayer#release()` in `onDestroy()`, also I added a test code based on Espresso to reproduce the memory leak issue.

here is the test code, and [here](https://github.com/sd148684/YouTubeDemo) for full demo code.

```
package com.examples.youtubeapidemo.play;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;
import android.util.Log;

import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.YouTubeAPIDemoActivity;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

/**
 * for YouTubePlayerView testing
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class PlayerViewTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<YouTubeAPIDemoActivity> mActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<YouTubeAPIDemoActivity>(YouTubeAPIDemoActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void testYouTubeMemoryLeaks() {
        int count = 0;
        while(count < 100) {
            onView(withText("Simple PlayerView")).perform(click());
            SystemClock.sleep(10000); // waiting for video start playing
            pressBack();
            count++;
            Log.i("PlayerViewTest", "count: " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm trying to implement it in my app now and it never releases the instance, causing a huge memory leak.

Comment: @Drew I found a dirty workaround, it works, but I would never encourage anyone to implement it. I noticed  `com.google.android.youtube` process can be killed manually by `activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.google.android.youtube");`, which requires permission `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` and must executed after a youtube player instance released.

Comment: My implementation is kill the process every 10 YouTube Player initialization, it works well and passed my tests, but I still think kill other process manually is definite a bad idea. Also I checked crash statistics from crash stats platform, I found out there're quite few users faced the OOM crash,(1~2 times per week, compares to 50k daily active users, it may related to my app's design, only few users have patient to browser over 30+ vids), then I decided to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the bug occurrence by putting youtube calls (like youtubePlayer.loadVideo(), cueVideo(), getCurrentTimeMillis() etc.) in a try catch block and catch the IllegalStateException exception then reinitialize youtube player.

and worked around it by catching these exceptions and restart activity,

see my answer on this thread : 
[Getting a lot of crashes from android youtube player api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419493/getting-a-lot-of-crashes-from-android-youtube-player-api/46983904#46983904)